# Can pagespeed.web.dev test hls/dash video players?

Tags: video-streaming

Can pagespeed.web.dev test hls/dash video players? We tried & the tool triggered the download of the fallback mp4 file not the abr streaming file. That skewed our results.

The fallback mp4 file, which loads when the our player can't play the abr streaming file gave our page a poor score. Is there a recommendation for using the tool for pages with hls/dash streaming video players?